# hive flattening JSON string

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive

Im trying to convert the below json string stored in hive table.

Input:

```
COL1   JSON_STRING
1      {"COL2": {"REFA": "9", "REFB": "9"}, "COL3": {"REFA": "80000.0000", "REFB": "80000.0000"}, "COL4": {"REFA": "0.0000", "REFB": "0.0000"}}
```

Expected output:

```
COL1  REF           COL2     COL3    COL4
1     REFA          9        80000   0
1     REFB          9        80001   0
1     DIFFERENCE    0        -1      0
```

Written the following code, to attain partial result

```
SELECT  
COL1,
COL2_REFA,COL2_REFB,(COL2_REFA-COL2_REFB) COL2_DIFFERENCE,
COL3_REFA,COL3_REFB,(COL3_REFA-COL3_REFB) COL3_DIFFERENCE,
COL4_REFA,COL4_REFB,(COL4_REFA-COL4_REFB) COL4_DIFFERENCE,
FROM  
TABLE T1 
LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(T1.JSON_STRING,'COL2','COL3','COL4') T2 AS `COL2`,`COL3`,`COL4`
LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(T2.COL2,'REFA','REFB') T3 AS `COL2_REFA`,`COL2_REFB`
LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(T2.COL3,'REFA','REFB') T4 AS `COL3_REFA`,`COL3_REFB`
LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(T2.COL4,'REFA','REFB') T5 AS `COL4_REFA`,`COL4_REFB`
```

Result for above query:

```
COL1    COL2_REFA   COL2_REFB   COL2_DIFF   COL3_REFA   COL3_REFB   COL3_DIFF   COL4_REFA   COL4_REFB   COL4_DIFF
1       9           9           0           80000       80001       -1          0           0           0
```

Not sure, whether that's efficient approach, for flattening the nested json string. How to attain the expected output in efficient way? Query also need to be compatible in pyspark sql(2.4).

Thanks

Comment: No..Using Cloudera..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Srinivas, for pointing me in right direction. With your query, other columns can't be selected apart from JSON string.
Thrown with below error.

```
UDTF's are not supported outside the SELECT clause
```

Used LATERAL VIEW with INLINE UDT. It worked. I'm posting this query for other users, who have such use case scenario.

```
select T1.COL1,T2.* from 
(select 1 COL1,'{"COL2": {"REFA": "9", "REFB": "9"}, "COL3": {"REFA": "80000.0000", "REFB": "80001.0000"}, "COL4": {"REFA": "0.0000", "REFB": "0.0000"}}' as JSON_STRING) as T1
lateral view 
inline(
    array(
        named_struct(                
            'SYSTEM',
            'REFA',
            'COL2',
            get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL2.REFA'),
            'COL3',
            get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL3.REFA'),
            'COL4',
            get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL4.REFA')
        ),
        named_struct(
            'SYSTEM',
            'REFB',
            'COL2',
            get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL2.REFB'),
            'COL3',
            get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL3.REFB'),
            'COL4',
            get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL4.REFB')
        ),
        named_struct(
            'SYSTEM',
            'DIFFERENCE',
            'COL2',
            (get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL2.REFA')-get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL2.REFB')),
            'COL3',
            (get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL3.REFA')-get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL3.REFB')),
            'COL4',
            (get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL4.REFA')-get_json_object(T1.JSON_STRING,'$.COL4.REFB'))
        )
    )
) T2 as SYSTEM,COL2,COL3,COL4
```

Result:

```
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| t1.col1  |  t2.system  | t2.col2  |   t2.col3   | t2.col4  |
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+
| 1        | REFA        | 9        | 80000.0000  | 0.0000   |
| 1        | REFB        | 9        | 80001.0000  | 0.0000   |
| 1        | DIFFERENCE  | 0.0      | -1.0        | 0.0      |
+----------+-------------+----------+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Check below solution

```
SELECT
        COL1,
        inline(
            array(
                named_struct(                
                    'REF',
                    'REFA',
                    'COL2',
                    get_json_object(data,'$.COL2.REFA'),
                    'COL3',
                    get_json_object(data,'$.COL3.REFA'),
                    'COL4',
                    get_json_object(data,'$.COL4.REFA')
                ),
                named_struct(
                    'REF',
                    'REFB',
                    'COL2',
                    get_json_object(data,'$.COL2.REFB'),
                    'COL3',
                    get_json_object(data,'$.COL3.REFB'),
                    'COL4',
                    get_json_object(data,'$.COL4.REFB')
                ),
                named_struct(
                    'REF',
                    'DIFFERENCE',
                    'COL2',
                    (get_json_object(data,'$.COL2.REFA') - get_json_object(data,'$.COL2.REFB')),
                    'COL3',
                    (get_json_object(data,'$.COL3.REFA') - get_json_object(data,'$.COL3.REFB')),
                    'COL4',
                    (get_json_object(data,'$.COL4.REFA') - get_json_object(data,'$.COL4.REFB'))
                )
            )
        )
FROM source
```

Output

```
+----+----------+----+----------+------+
|COL1|REF       |COL2|COL3      |COL4  |
+----+----------+----+----------+------+
|1   |REFA      |9   |80000.0000|0.0000|
|1   |REFB      |9   |80001.0000|0.0000|
|1   |DIFFERENCE|0.0 |-1.0      |0.0   |
+----+----------+----+----------+------+
```

Comment: Thanks!. Will JSON parsing(get_json_object) will happen multiple times for same row?

Comment: Yes, It will call `get_json_object` for multiple times.. for same row.. Performance side It is far better than `LATERAL VIEW`

Comment: Raja, Please check & accept if it answered for your questions.

Comment: Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10081]: UDTF's are not supported outside the SELECT clause, nor nested in expressions (state=42000,code=10081).INLINE is not working in SELECT clause.

Comment: Looks we cant use INLINE UDTF in SELECT CLAUSE. Only option would be to use LATERAL. I will modify it and test it.